# How to save data in global environment with same ending automatically with their names into a folder on PC?

Tags: r, dataframe, save

I would like to save single dataframes with the same name they have in the environment automatically without writing the name for each dataframe itself in the code. How can I do that?

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(94756)
Data_Date03.03.22Time10.23.45.xlsx <- matrix(sample(seq(-1,100, 0.11),70, replace = TRUE),ncol = 5) 
Data_Date03.03.22Time10.23.45.xlsx <- as.tibble(Data_Date03.03.22Time10.23.45.xlsx)

Data_Date03.03.22Time10.26.36.xlsx <- matrix(sample(seq(-1,100, 0.11),70, replace = TRUE),ncol = 5)  
Data_Date03.03.22Time10.26.36.xlsx <- as.tibble(Data_Date03.03.22Time10.26.36.xlsx)
Data_Date03.03.22Time10.26.36.xlsx[3,1] <- NA
Data_Date03.03.22Time10.26.36.xlsx[6,1] <- NA

Data_Date03.03.22Time10.27.12.xlsx <- matrix(sample(seq(-1,100, 0.11), 70,replace = TRUE),ncol = 5)  
Data_Date03.03.22Time10.27.12.xlsx <- as.tibble(Data_Date03.03.22Time10.27.12.xlsx)
Data_Date03.03.22Time10.27.12.xlsx[4,1] <- NA


data <- list(Data_Date03.03.22Time10.23.45.xlsx, Data_Date03.03.22Time10.26.36.xlsx, Data_Date03.03.22Time10.27.12.xlsx)
```

The result in my PC "save documents" folder should be:
Data_Date03.03.22Time10.23.45.xlsx |
Data_Date03.03.22Time10.26.36.xlsx |
Data_Date03.03.22Time10.27.12.xlsx |
...as three single excel documents.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would write excel files in your working directory.

```
purrr::imap(mget(ls(pattern = '^Data_Date')), writexl::write_xlsx)
```

If you want to write it to specific folder, you can do -

```
purrr::imap(mget(ls(pattern = '^Data_Date')), 
        ~writexl::write_xlsx(.x, paste0('/path/to/folder/', .y)))
```

---

Explanation -

`ls` with `pattern` returns names of the object in global environment which has the pattern in their name.

```
ls(pattern = '^Data_Date')
#[1] "Data_Date03.03.22Time10.23.45.xlsx" "Data_Date03.03.22Time10.26.36.xlsx"
#[3] "Data_Date03.03.22Time10.27.12.xlsx"
```

`mget` would create a named list of tibble. `imap` is used to write the tibbles to excel files where `.x` is the tibble whereas `.y` is name of the object.

Comment: What do code differently that my excel sheets show NA as well? At the moment the cells are empty in excel, althought in R there's NA... I use the same code like explained above.